# Can I configure NetBeans editor to look more like Notepad++?

Tags: javascript, netbeans

I am working with a large project with many Javascript functions but I find the NetBeans Navigator inconvenient to move from function to function.  A more desirable interface in my opinion is the Notepad++ feature which allows you to collapse the function code into a single line in the source file.  This way, I can more easily move about the source and work on a particular function without having to scroll through a lot of lines to get to the function I want to work at.

Is there a way to configure NetBeans to allow collapsing of function code this way?

Thanks,
Dominic

Comment: Afraid I'm having problems with this.  I'm new to NetBeans.  Suppose I have a block of code as:  function clearCheckMarks(){  some code }.  How can I collapse that block so that only "clearCheckmarks()" appears in the editor?  I tried using the Ctrl+- keys and nothing happens.

Comment: Have you took a look at [the dukumentation](https://ui.netbeans.org/docs/ui/code_folding/cf_uispec.html)?

Comment: [This](https://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/entry/javascript_code_folding) might also be helpful :)

Comment: Thanks for replying.  Yes. I have set up folding using Options/Editor/Folding and then restarted Netbeans but no folding is showing up in my code and also when I for example block a function and then press Ctrl+"-" nothing is happening.

Comment: Also I have Netbeans IDE 8.1

Comment: mabye you have to reinstall netbeans